# Jquery dataTable does not enable sorting after reinitialising

Tags: datatables

I have the following initialisation of a dataTable:

```
$('#historical-plan').dataTable({
   "bDestroy":true,
   "bRetrieve":true,
   "aLengthMenu": [[52, 104, -1], [52, 104, "All"]],
   "iDisplayLength": 52  });
```

Even though the first time the table works as expected and let you sort the columns ..all the other times it works except from the sorting. It doesn't let you sort the columns of the table.
Any ideas will be very much appreciated!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've supplied - see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/HEDvf/2142/) for confirmation.  So there must be something else that's causing the problem. You haven't posted much code so it's hard to guess.

Comment: The problem is when the table gets re initialized. At first it works as expected, but when you hide it and then reload it again then it happens and I can't figure why. I think it has something to to with the bDestroy & bRetrieve properties.

Comment: I don't know if this helps ... but the table data are getting changed each time the user selects another link and I haven't used the bServerSide property should I use it?

Comment: what do you mean 'another link'? If your data is coming from the server then yes, you should use `bServerSide`.